# Using Unix tools to process text: search and replace all text that are not between some lines

Tags: python, perl, bash, sed, awk

I'm looking to do some text processing on a bunch of *.org files.  I would like to change the following in each file:

```
[my description](link)
```

to

```
[[link][my description]]
```

,

```
`some text`
```

to

```
=some text=
```

,

```
## some heading
```

to

```
** some heading
```

,

```
*some italics*
```

to

```
/some italics/
```

, and

```
**some bold**
```

to

```
*some bold*
```

.  Yes, this IS markdown syntax to org-mode syntax. I AM aware of [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).  The caveat is that I want the above changes, except when they occur in the following block:

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
don't want above changes to take place in this block
...
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

Hence, I can't use pandoc.  I'd like to process these files according to the above requirements using some kind of unix script: awk, sed, python, perl, bash, etc.  Once I have a working script, I can modify it and learn from it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler and more robust to convert the examples to Markdown literal blocks, then run `pandoc`, then revert the example blocks to your preferred format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Perl Solution

This is the result of the simplifying changes I suggested for @jkerian’s script: use the flipflop operator and `-p`.  I’ve also fixed his regexes to use the correct `$1` and `$2` in the RHS, altered delimiters from `s///` to `s:::` to avoid LTS *(“Leaning Toothpick Syndrome”)*, and added `/x` to improve readability. There was  a logic error in dealing with bold and italics, which I’ve fixed.  I  added comments showing what the transform should be in each case, corresponding to the original problem description, and aligned the RHS of the transforms to make them easier to read.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
#
# the -p option makes this a pass-through filter
#####################################################

# omit protected region
next if /^#\+BEGIN_EXAMPLE/ .. /^#\+END_EXAMPLE/;

# `some text`                      ⇒   =some text=
s: ` ( [^`]* ) `                       :=$1=:gx;

# [desc](link)                     ⇒   [[link][desc]]
s: \[ ( [^]]* ) \] \( ( [^)]* ) \)     :[[$2][$1]]:gx;

# ^## some heading ⇒ ** some heading
#      NB: can't use /x here or would have to use ugly \#
s:^##:**:;   

# *some italics*                   ⇒   /some italics/
s: (?!< \* ) \* ( [^*]+ ) \* (?! \*)   :/$1/:gx;

# **some bold**                    ⇒   *some bold*
s: \*{2} ( [^*]+ ) \*{2}               :*$1*:gx;
```

See how easy that is? Just 6 simple lines of eminently readable code in Perl. It’s easy in Perl because Perl is specifically designed to make writing  this sort of filter super-easy, and Python is not. Python has separate design goals.

Although you could certainly rewrite this in Python, it wouldn’t be worth the bother because Python simply  isn’t designed for this sort of thing. Python’s missing the `-p` “make-me-a-filter” flag for an implicit loop and implicit print. Python is missing the implicit accumulator variable. Python is missing built-in regexes. Python is missing the `s///` operator.  And Python is missing the stateful flipflop operator.  All those contribute to making the Perl solution much much much easier to read, write, and maintain than the Python solution.

However, you should not get the idea that this always holds.  It doesn’t. In other areas, you can come up with problems that Python comes out ahead in those areas. But not here. It’s because this filter thing is a focused specialty area for Perl, and it isn’t for Python.

The Python solution would consequently be much longer, noisier,  and harder to read — and therefore harder to maintain — than this easy Perl version, all because Perl was designed to make easy things easy, and this is one of its target application areas. Try rewriting this in Python and notice how nasty it is. Sure it’s possible, but not worth the hassle, or the maintenance nightmare.

## Python Version

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2

from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import re

if (sys.version_info[0] == 2):
    sys.stderr.write("%s: legacy Python detected! Please upgrade to v3+\n"
                   % sys.argv[0] )
    ##sys.exit(2)

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append("/dev/stdin")

flip_rx = re.compile(r'^#\+BEGIN_EXAMPLE')
flop_rx = re.compile(r'^#\+END_EXAMPLE')

#EG# `some text`  -->   =some text=
lhs_backticks = re.compile(r'` ( [^`]* ) `', re.VERBOSE)
rhs_backticks =            r'=\1='

#EG# [desc](link)  -->  [[link][desc]]
lhs_desclink  = re.compile(r' \[ ( [^]]* ) \] \( ( [^)]* ) \) ', re.VERBOSE)
rhs_desclink  =            r'[[\2][\1]]'

#EG# ^## some heading  -->  ** some heading
lhs_header    = re.compile(r'^##')
rhs_header    =            r'**'

#EG# *some italics*  -->  /some italics/
lhs_italics   = re.compile(r' (?!< \* ) \* ( [^*]+ ) \* (?! \*)  ', re.VERBOSE)
rhs_italics   =            r'/\1/'

## **some bold**  -->  *some bold*
lhs_bold      = re.compile(r'\*{2} ( [^*]+ ) \*{2}', re.VERBOSE)
rhs_bold      =            r'*\1*'

errcnt = 0

flipflop = "flip"

for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    try:
        filehandle = open(filename, "r")
    except IOError as oops:
        errcnt = errcnt + 1
        sys.stderr.write("%s: can't open '%s' for reading: %s\n"
                      % ( sys.argv[0],    filename,        oops) )
    else:
        try:
            for line in filehandle:

                new_flipflop = None

                if flipflop == "flip":
                    if flip_rx.search(line):
                        new_flipflop = "flop"
                elif flipflop == "flop":
                    if flop_rx.search(line):
                        new_flipflop = "flip"
                else:
                    raise FlipFlop_SNAFU

                if flipflop != "flop":
                    line = lhs_backticks . sub ( rhs_backticks, line)
                    line = lhs_desclink  . sub ( rhs_desclink,  line)
                    line = lhs_header    . sub ( rhs_header,    line)
                    line = lhs_italics   . sub ( rhs_italics,   line)
                    line = lhs_bold      . sub ( rhs_bold,      line)                        
                print(line, end="")

                if new_flipflop != None:
                    flipflop = new_flipflop

        except IOError as oops:
            errcnt = errcnt + 1
            sys.stderr.write("%s: can't read '%s': %s\n"
              % ( sys.argv[0],    filename,        oops) )
        finally:
            try:
                filehandle.close()
            except IOError as oops:
                errcnt = errcnt + 1
                sys.stderr.write("%s: can't close '%s': %s\n"
                  % ( sys.argv[0],    filename,        oops) )

if errcnt == 0:
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    sys.exit(1)
```

## Summary

It’s important to use the right tool for the right job. For this task, that tool is Perl, which took only 7 lines. There are only 7 things to do, but don’t try telling Python that.  It’s like being back to assembly language with too many interrupt stacks.  Python at 72 lines is clearly not  cut out for this kind of work, and all the painful complexity and noisey unreadable code shows you just exactly why.  Bug rate per line of code is the same no matter the language, so if you have your choice between writing N lines of code or 10*N lines of code, there is no choice.

Comment: @jkerian: no, definitely not.

Comment: I guess I have to question two paragraphs of preaching on the difficulties of python... when the reality is you would only need 3-4 lines of "loop over STDIN and print" surrounding essentially the same regexes. I mean, yeah it's "a bit" shorter... but we're not talking about much difference here. There are significantly more complex filters where I might tend to agree... but this really isn't a strong example.

Comment: @jkerian: Point taken. You’re right that it’s most handwaving if I don’t show both versions. I'll post an equivalent Python program and you’ll see what I mean. I’m trying to teach people that different tools do things better or worse than others, that it’s not all an equivalence thing. I’d like people to develop a feel for which sorts of tasks are more easily accomplished in one tool versus in another one. Gimme a couple seconds and I’ll put the other version up.

Comment: That python version isn't even close to fair. Where's your check for perl6? Where's your completely irrelevant string variables for the various parts of the substitution? Where's your error handling (and yes, perl is just as exposed). You also seem to have chosen the most verbose possible method of checking for the commented blocks.

Comment: @jkerian: You are making a category error by equating perl5 and 6 with python2 and 3.  Python3 replaces Python2, which is dead.  Perl6 is a different language and no more replaces Perl5 than Java replaces C.

Comment: I cannot see how you can possibly think that python code is defensible. If I was trying to make a joke perl version that took up 100s of lines, I could certainly do that as well. I won't argue that perl is the better tool for the job, but your python code here is such a caricature that no one with a passing knowledge of python is going to take your comparison seriously.

Comment: @jkerian: The python code is written that way for the simple reason that it is meant to do the same thing as the perl code is doing. The point is that perl takes care of a great deal of automatic stuff for you with this particular problem domain that in python you must laboriously handcode.  And no, I don't consider stack dumps **EVER** to be acceptable. They are equivalent to BUS ERROR CORE DUMPED and simply show that your program has a stoopid bug.

Comment: @jkerian: I expect the flipflop operator supported. I expect my patterns compiled before the program begins. I expect left and right hand portions of my substitutions to be in the same area of the program so I can see that these line up correct. I expect it to work like any normal Unix filter by operating on all input files given in argv, or absent that, on stdin. I expect my patterns to be legible. I expect error and warning messages that state the name of the offending program, syscall, &arg, all without idiot stack dumps. My 7 lines of Perl code do all those things. And 72 lines of Python.

Comment: Your 72 lines of python aren't even close, and the rediculous gold-plating and exceptions-that-are-really-return-codes sortof demonstrates that the code is unuseable in a larger project anyway, regardless of what you say about stack traces. If you DID decide you were going to pre-compile your regexes in python, you'd obviously use a set of tuples for generation, use a generator for pre-compiling those regexes, and then applying them. Your insanely verbose flipFlop code isn't even close to what was done in perl. Where's your pointless "FlipFlop exception"?

Comment: Down voting because the Python example is a joke.  Yes, I generally use Perl if I'm writing a filter, because the -p flag is so useful, but if I really needed to write one in Python, I'd just loop over stdin, and use "cat $* | filter.py" if I needed to handle concatenated files.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for something like the following perl script

```
while(<>) {
    if /#\+BEGIN_EXAMPLE/ .. /#\+END_EXAMPLE/ {
        print;
        next;
    }
    s/`([^`]*)`/=\1=/g;
    s/\[([^]]*)\]\(([^)]*)\)/[[\2][\1]]/g;
    s/^##/**/;
    s/\*([^\*]+)\*/\/\1\//g;
    s/\*\/([^\/]+)\/\*/*\1*/g;
    print;
}
```

Run it with `cat testfile | perl scriptname.pl`

For a non-silly version of python. Note: Perl is the right tool for the job, but tchrist's python version is such a bad joke that it had to be fixed.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput
import re
import sys

sys.tracebacklimit=0    #For those desperate to hide tracebacks in one-off scripts
example = 0
for line in fileinput.input():
    if example==0 and re.match(r'^#\+BEGIN_EXAMPLE',line):
        example+=1
    elif example>=1:
        if re.match(r'^#\+END_EXAMPLE',line): example-=1
    else:
        line = re. sub (r'` ( [^`]* ) `',                      r'=\1=',       line, 0, re.VERBOSE)
        line = re. sub (r'\[ ( [^]]* ) \] \( ( [^)]* ) \) ',   r'[[\2][\1]]', line, 0, re.VERBOSE)
        line = re. sub (r'^\#\#',                              r'**',         line, 0, re.VERBOSE)
        line = re. sub (r'(?!< \* ) \* ( [^*]+ ) \* (?! \*)',  r'/\1/',       line, 0, re.VERBOSE)
        line = re. sub (r'\*{2} ( [^*]+ ) \*{2}',              r'*\1*',       line, 0, re.VERBOSE)
    print(line, end="")
```

Comment: You are not printing the example blocks at all?

Comment: @jkerian: Your `$flag` is unneeded.  Just do a `next if /#\+BEGIN_EXAMPLE/ .. /#\+END_EXAMPLE/` at the top of your loop. Perl is designed to make this sort of thing very easy: the flipflop operator has all the stateful logic you need. See how that works?

Comment: @tripleee: If they want to print the protected zone, too, then they should put the `print` in a `continue` block instead.  In fact, they should really just use `perl -p`.

Comment: wow... negative voting for a (as far as I can see) working example that someone improved on for a solution.... nice.

Comment: This program has a severe performance bug because you seem to be recompiling all your patterns for each and every line of input.  That is just nuts. So a 1024-line file deserves 7168 calls to regcomp? I don't think so. The right number of regex compilations is 7, because those are constant strings. Does the `re` library cache the compiled form in the syntax tree where it belongs, or do you waste your life? Also, what makes you think examples nest?

Comment: -1 for using \1 and \2 in the RHS of the  Perl substitutions. That's just wrong.  Turn on warnings. -1 for style demerits by using the delimiter in the pattern. -1 for backslashing things you don't need to in bracketed charclasses.  -1 for the python version having a bug in that it spits an ugly stack dump all over your face if you pass it a file with access problems.

Comment: @tchrist: a) the performance difference between compiled and not is about 15% (and yes, perl is blazingly fast by comparison... not arguing that) b) I waste my life? on a 72 line python version when a 17 line would do? c) examples nesting was something I just decided to do... maybe they can, maybe they can't (for example converting a page describing the syntax of that page). d) If you seriously vote people down for using a delimiter in a regex pattern instead of switching the delimiter... you have issues. e) Ugly stack dump??! I just tested that, EXACT SAME ERROR MESSAGE AS PERL.

Comment: @tchrist: [`re` module caches the last 100 patterns](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/re.py#l224).

Answer (score 1):

Just for grins, here's my version of the python solution:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput, functools, re, sys

# For those desperate to hide tracebacks in one-off scripts
sys.tracebacklimit = 0
# Precompile all our patterns for speed
begin_example = re.compile(r'^#\+BEGIN_EXAMPLE').match
end_example = re.compile(r'^#\+END_EXAMPLE').match
# Use partial to eliminate lookups inside our loop
fixes = [ functools.partial(re.compile(x[0], x[2]).sub, x[1]) for x in
          (r'` ( [^`]* ) `',                      r'=\1=',       re.VERBOSE),
          (r'\[ ( [^]]* ) \] \( ( [^)]* ) \) ',   r'[[\2][\1]]', re.VERBOSE),
          (r'^\#\#',                              r'**',         re.VERBOSE),
          (r'(?!< \* ) \* ( [^*]+ ) \* (?! \*)',  r'/\1/',       re.VERBOSE),
          (r'\*{2} ( [^*]+ ) \*{2}',              r'*\1*',       re.VERBOSE),
          ]

inside = False
for line in fileinput.input():
    if inside:
        if end_example(line):
            inside = False
    else:
        if begin_example(line):
            inside = True
        for fixup in fixes:
            line = fixup(line)
    print(line, end='')
```